# how to display grails error from bootstrap

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

I just found annoying bug from my bootstrap.groovy. If I did a mistake for example, like undeclared variable, the apps keep running and then when I tried to access the apps from web it will display

> HTTP Status 404 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description The requested resource ()
>   is not available. Apache
>   Tomcat/6.0-snapshot

in the console there is no error messages appear ... so it makes confuse. suppose I edit 10 bootstrap and in one of them I did make a mistakes, it would become so difficult to find that little bug.

any idea how to solve this problem ? is it a tips to display those errors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing in your bootstrap, but if its failing when you're saving domain objects, then you can log those as errors the same way you would in a controller. If you want the errors to go to a console, just set up a console appender:

```
//Remember, save calls validate()
if(!myObject.save()) {
    myObject.errors.allErrors.each {
        log.error it
    }
}
```

### References:

- [Logging in grails](http://grails.org/doc/1.2.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2%20Logging)
- [Validating constraints](http://grails.org/doc/1.2.x/guide/7.%20Validation.html#7.2%20Validating%20Constraints)

Answer (score 0):

For other time use you can use this show error method not only on domain object like myObject.save() but also any method having an exception or a service like this one :

```
def searchService 

searchService.search(person)  // inside hibernate create criteria or any db actitvity or ...

seachService.errors.allErrors,each {
flash.message = message(code:'default.search.error.message',default : it) //see it in freindly view
 //Or println("${new Date()}"it)
}



you need a lable flash message on your in case of other files than bootstrap 

<g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'domainClassName.label', default: 'what ever')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>


    <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
```